# OpenCV changing the detection colour

Tags: c, opencv

I have a downloaded code from website which is a paint tools by using color detection. And this program default detection color is yellow, but I wish to change the detection color from yellow to other color but I am unable to understand the code and does not know which part of the code should I edit in order to change the detection color.

Here is code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define blue  CV_RGB(0,0,255)
#define green CV_RGB(0,255,0)
#define red   CV_RGB(255,0,0)
#define white CV_RGB(255,255,255)
#define black CV_RGB(0,0,0)

void ClearScreen(IplImage* imgScribble, IplImage* imgDrawing)
{
cvSet(imgScribble, black);
cvSet(imgDrawing, white);
}

IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* img, CvScalar& lowerBound, CvScalar& upperBound)
{
// Convert the image into an HSV image
IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound, imgThreshed);

cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
return imgThreshed;
}

int main()
{
// controls
double area_limit = 700;
CvScalar lowerBound = cvScalar(20, 100, 100);  // yellow
CvScalar upperBound = cvScalar(30, 255, 255);

// defaults
int lineThickness = 2;
CvScalar lineColor = blue;


CvCapture* capture = 0;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
if(!capture)
{
    cout << "Could not initialize capturing...\n";
    return -1;
}

// This image holds the "scribble" data...
// the tracked positions of the pointer object
IplImage* imgScribble = NULL;


IplImage* imgColorPanel = 0;
imgColorPanel = cvLoadImage( "cvPaint.panel",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR ); // load the panel image. (This is a png image, not designed/included in the source code!) 
if(!imgColorPanel)
{
    cout << "cvPaint.panel is not found !!! \n";
    return -1;
}

IplImage* imgDrawing = 0;
imgDrawing = cvCreateImage( cvSize(cvQueryFrame(capture)->width,cvQueryFrame(capture)->height),
                            cvQueryFrame(capture)->depth,     //Bit depth per channel
                            3  //number of channels
                          );
cvSet(imgDrawing, white);

CvFont font, fontbig;
cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, .6, 0, 2, CV_AA);
cvInitFont( &fontbig, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3, .6, 0, 3, CV_AA);

int confirm_close = 10, confirm_clear = 20; // counters for clear and exit confirmation
char buffer [50]; // buffer for cvPutText
int image_num = 0; // to keep track of image numbers for saving
int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;

while(true)
{
    IplImage* frame = 0;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frame)
        break;
    cvFlip(frame,NULL,1); // flip the frame to overcome mirroring problem



    // If this is the first frame, we need to initialize it
    if(imgScribble == NULL)
        imgScribble = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 3);

    // Median filter to decrease the background noise
    cvSmooth( frame, frame,
              CV_MEDIAN,
              5, 5 //parameters for filter, in this case it is filter size
            );


    // Holds the thresholded image (tracked color -> white, the rest -> black)
    IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(frame,lowerBound,upperBound);

    // Calculate the moments to estimate the position of the object
    CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
    cvMoments(imgThresh, moments, 1);


    // The actual moment values
    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

    // Holding the last and current positions
    int lastX = posX;
    int lastY = posY;

    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;


    if(moment10/area>=0 && moment10/area < 1280 && moment01/area >=0 && moment01/area < 1280
       && area>area_limit /* to control the limit */ )
    {
        posX = moment10/area;
        posY = moment01/area;
    }



    CvPoint cvpoint = cvPoint(150,30); // location of the text
    if(posX < 90 && posY > 400) // clear
    {
        lineColor = white; // white color works as eraser
        cvPutText( frame, "Eraser selected.", cvpoint, &font, white );
        sprintf (buffer, "Clearing the screen in %d",confirm_clear); // count-down for clearing the screen
        cvPutText( frame, buffer, cvPoint(150,70), &font, red );
        confirm_clear--;
        if(confirm_clear < 0) // confirm in 10 frames before clearing
        {
            confirm_clear = 20;
            sprintf (buffer, "d0%d.jpg",image_num++);
            cvSaveImage(buffer ,imgDrawing); // save the frame into an image
            ClearScreen(imgScribble,imgDrawing);
            cvPutText( frame, "Cleared the screen.", cvPoint(150,110), &font, white );
        }
    }
    else if(posX  > 540 && posY > 360)  // blue
    {
        lineColor = blue;
        cvPutText( frame, "Blue color selected.", cvpoint, &font, blue );
    }

    else if(posX  > 540 && posY > 200 && posY < 280) // green
    {
        lineColor = green;
        cvPutText( frame, "Green color selected.", cvpoint, &font, green );
    }

    else if(posX  > 540 && posY < 120) // red
    {
        lineColor = red;
        cvPutText( frame, "Red color selected.", cvpoint, &font, red );
    }

    else if(posX > 0 && posX  < 90 && posY > 0 && posY < 120) // exit
    {
        sprintf (buffer, "EXITING in %d",confirm_close);
        cvPutText( frame, buffer, cvpoint, &font, red );
        confirm_close--;
        if(confirm_close < 0) // confirm in 10 frames before exit
            break;
    }
    else if(posX < 90 && posY > 130 && posY < 390) // line thickness
    {
        lineThickness = 6 - ( posY/60-1 );  // change the thickness of line from 1 - 5 based on posY
    }


    sprintf (buffer, "%d",lineThickness);
    cvPutText( frame, buffer, cvPoint(40,255), &fontbig, lineColor );

    double diff_X = lastX-posX;
    double diff_Y = lastY-posY;
    double magnitude = sqrt(   pow(diff_X,2) + pow(diff_Y,2)   );
    // We want to draw a line only if its a valid position
    //if(lastX>0 && lastY>0 && posX>0 && posY>0)
    if(magnitude > 0 && magnitude < 100 && posX > 120 && posX<530)
    {
        // Draw a line from the previous point to the current point
        cvLine(imgDrawing, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), lineColor, lineThickness,CV_AA);
    }


    //cout << "position = " << posX << "\t" <<  posY << "\t";
    //cout << "moment = " << moment10 << "\t" <<  moment01 << "\n";
    //cout << "d->" << magnitude << endl;
    //cout << "area = " << area << endl;

    // Add the scribbling image and the frame...
    cvAdd(imgDrawing, imgScribble, imgDrawing);

    // Combine everything in frame
    cvAnd(frame, imgDrawing, frame);
    cvAnd(imgColorPanel, frame, frame);

    cvShowImage("Threshold", imgThresh);
    cvShowImage("Drawing", imgDrawing);
    cvShowImage("Video", frame);


    int c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if(c==27)  //ESC key
        break;
    //else if(c==49) // 1 key


    cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh);
    delete moments;
}

 cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
 cvReleaseImage(&imgColorPanel);
 cvReleaseImage(&imgScribble);

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How about the second line in `main()` with a comment `// yellow` after it?

Comment: ya i had read it and understand that line is the line for chging the color.. but wat tat 2 lines mean? does it run RGB? HSV？

Comment: Default OpenCV color format is BGR.

Comment: `CvScalar lowerBound = cvScalar(20, 100, 100);` normally is in BGR format but depends on the data type of the image. `CV_RGB(0,0,255)` is in RGB order. But please if not necessary remove all that code and start again without IplImages but cv::Mat and c++ syntax instead!!

Comment: ok ty for info, and 1 more question. So the `CvScalar lowerBound = cvScalar(20, 100, 100);` and `CvScalar upperBound = cvScalar(30, 255, 255);` stand for the range of the color detection???

Comment: "I have a downloaded code from website" - please, be more picky here in the future. anything using IplImages should be buried under a big rock. DO NOT USE IT !